# How to stop the airodump-ng command after 5 seconds

Tags: bash, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to run the airodum-ng command for 5 seconds then stop it and save the output to the network variable, so I can print the output to a whiptail gui. Unfortunately the command just never stops running does anyone know how to fix this. I tried the timeout method witch you can see here and i also tried to use sleep but no luck.

```
function aircrack() {
  sudo airmon-ng check kill
  name=($(sudo /usr/sbin/airmon-ng ))
  sudo airmon-ng start ${name[5]}
  name=($(sudo /usr/sbin/airmon-ng ))
  **netwroks=($(timeout 5s sudo airodump-ng ${name[5]}))**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the non-root `timeout` tries to kill a root process and fails.
The correct way to use timeout with `sudo` would be:

```
sudo timeout 5s airodump-ng ${name[5]}
```

Comment: I tried making that change but still not luck it just runs forever